# How to make MacBook Pro sharing Wi-Fi from iPad?

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, ipad, network, wifi

I connected from iPad to MacBook Pro (mid 2012) by USB. I turned on iPad personal hotspot and Internet Sharing works.

Now I want to share my MacBook Pro's internet connection too. I made the following setting but it is not working for me. In Wi-Fi options I set the following: Channel: 1, Security: WPA2 Personal.

How can I make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting situation and one that didn't, for me at least, bring any clear-cut obvious answer. Here is what I found.

First, I created a very similar setup to yours. I connected my iPhone to my Macbook Pro and tethered USB. I had to forget my current wifi network so that I could actually share over my computer's wifi. So, first, double check that your computer doesn't have an active wifi connection (I couldn't tell from your screenshot). A MacBook Pro cannot receive and send a wifi connection - it is a one way street.

I then tried creating a network from the USB connection. This did not work. I then connected my ethernet cable and confirmed that internet sharing worked fine and it was just something about the USB that was problematic. I next proceeded to test Bluetooth tethering. I connected to my phone solely over Bluetooth and once again the computer created a wifi connection. (By the way, the wifi icon changes to a block of gray with an arrow pointing up when the sharing is working). I confirmed on my iPad that it created a perfectly good, and connectable wifi.

I went back and connected only through my USB connection and once again, the computer would *not create a wifi*. One thing to note about working with this is that there really aren't any errors. If it doesn't work, the only real way to tell is that it won't create a network. While that is fairly obvious, it would be nice to have some error saying why it won't share the USB connection.

The only thing I didn't try was rebooting, but I just started the computer this morning as it was shut down last night, so I see little chance that would work.

#### In conclusion:

I suggest that you either tether over Bluetooth (and sacrifice some speed, potentially), or just use your iPad to share wifi and Bluetooth.*

<sup>* *I'm a little curious why you don't do that anyway, but that doesn't matter.*</sup>

Comment: I made like you make in past. I connected iPad and MacBook by Bluetooth and it worked for me. I now connect by usb and I get this situation. Thank you for your answer, it very helps me. Unfortunately that it doesn't work by Bluetooth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible when using a shared network (you can share your internet connection through wifi if you're using ethernet).

Why can't you make a wifi hotspot directly from the iPad ?